# Use text field as contextual filter in views? Or related content not based on taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I'm trying to figure out if it would be possible to use text field as contextual filter in views?

Say I want to have EVA or block that takes certain Field-A from current node as filter. Then EVA or block shows other content type that has the same Field-A text.

Sort of related content but not based on taxonomy.

Comment: You would set up the contextual filter to get the current node id, then use ralationships

Comment: Well, indeed, I'm fine with relationships. But any more precise recipe?